# How to write unit test case using jasmine and karma in angular 7

Tags: angular, karma-jasmine, karma-coverage

I have to write unit test case for the below code in a function inside ts file

```
logout() {
this.cookieService.delete('deleted_cookie_name');
}

I have writtern like this using spy.

cookieService=jasmine.createSpyObj(['delete'])
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would have done something like below;

```
it('should delete cookie name', inject([CookieService], (cookieService: CookieService) => {
const serviceSpy = spyOn(cookieService, 'delete');
component.logout();
expect(serviceSpy).toHaveBeenCalled();
}
))
```